# docker-composeで作成したReactアプリがlocalhost以外の任意のホスト名から接続できる。

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, reactjs, network, docker-compose

create-react-appで作成されたReactのアプリに `localhost:3000` と `app.hoge.hoge:3000` というホスト名で同じページに接続出来ます。
reactアプリの環境変数HOSTやpacakege.json にホスト名を変更するような記述が見られないのにどうしてこのような動作をするのか不思議でたまりません。

アプリはフロントがReactでバックエンドがrails APIでAPIにリクエストを投げる際に同じ `app.hoge.hoge:8080/api/v1` みたいな感じで投げています。

おそらく　React側でhost名が設定されたのではなく docker-compose側でホスト名がバックエンドと同じになっていると思うのですが、どうのような設定をしたらこのようになるのか分からないです。 `docker networl create hoge` で作成されたネットワークにフロントとバックエンドのコンテナが接続してるような構成にはなっているのですが、 `app.hoge.hoge` を指定してる箇所が見つけられなくて根拠が見当たらないです。

お手隙の際に、ネットワーク周りに詳しい方教えて頂けないでしょうか。
宜しくお願い致します。他に必要な情報があれば教えて下さい。追記します。

Reactアプリが動作しているコンテナ内の `cat /etc/hosts` を確認しても　`app.hoge.hoge` の記載は見られなかったです。
やはりdockerでもなく react router dom 等 react側で制御されているのでしょうか？

Answer (score 0):

外部に建てたDNSサーバ（`app.hoge.hoge`）にアクセスして、それが `localhost` に接続を促してるためでした。そのため開発環境のパソコンのWifiを切断したら `app.hoge.hoge:3000` で接続できなくなりました。

dig app.hoge.hoge でDNSのサーバが動作してるか確認できるそうです。